# jQuery with multiple criteria

Tags: jquery

I have a table with multiple columns but some of them are hidden using display:none. In case, it helps, I'm using Footable to hide the entire column.
Cells can only have the letter P, otherwise they are empty. My problem is that on the last column I'm counting how many "P"s are on the row and I'm using this code:

```
$('td.last_column').html(function() {
var P = $(this).prevAll('td.column_p:contains(P)').length;
return P;
});
```

The problem is that it is also counting the cells that contains "P" but are hidden. Is there any easy way to get only the number of VISIBLE cells on the row that contain the letter P?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this works the way it's intended to, with the exception of showing the hidden cells' content as well, I'd suggest using the `:visible` selector to refine the selection to only those elements that are visible to the user, as well as containing the `P`:

```
$('td.last_column').html(function() {
    var P = $(this).prevAll('td.column_p:visible:contains(P)').length;
    return P;
});
```

You could also switch to using `siblings()` with a selector:

```
$('td.last_column').html(function() {
    var P = $(this).siblings(':visible:contains(P)').length;
    return P;
});
```

References:

- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately :visible is not doing the trick. Maybe :visible is considering the columns with "display:none" as visible?

Comment: Hi David, I created a live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/FVH5C/ but I can't hide the columns that doesn't contain "may" on the header. This is working on my code. Note that this is done using footable and adding the attributes data-hide and data-ignore. Any idea why it's not working on JsFiddle?

Comment: BTW, this is to keep track of classes attendances and I'm using Footable to display only the attendances of a given month, hidden all the columns that doesn't correspond to that month.
P = Present
A = Absent
T = Present but arrived Late
J = Absent (justified)

Comment: Please, use this one: http://jsfiddle.net/lucatros/3UN5L (I added the Bootstrap CSS just in case)

Comment: I've been playing a bit and the problems seems to be with Footable. I tried adding the style="display: none;" manually to the cells instead of using Footable and the code you suggested is working. I'm thinking that maybe the problem is that style="display: none;" is dynamically added by Footable and Jquery is not recognizing it. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try [**:visible**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Selects all elements that are visible.

```
$('td.last_column').html(function () {
    var P = $(this).prevAll('td.column_p:visible:contains(P)').length;
    return P;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned on the previous comment, for some reason :visible is not working.